# Why is my checkbox is unchecked after saving?

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I have created a checkbutton with Python (Django) like this:

in my views.py:

```
def list(response, list_id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=list_id)
    if response.method == "POST":  # If we are POST-ing something (saving, adding items, etc..)
        print(response.POST)
        if response.POST.get("save"):  # SAVING CHECK-BUTTONS
            for item in ls.listitem_set.all():  # Loop through all items
                if response.POST.get("c" + str(item.id)) == "clicked":  # Check if it has been clicked or not
                    item.complete = True
                else:
                    item.complete = False
                item.save()
        elif response.POST.get("newItem"):  # ADDING ITEM TO LIST
            txt = response.POST.get("new")  # Get text-input by name
            if len(txt) > 2:  # Check for valid input
                ls.listitem_set.create(text=txt, complete=False)
            else:
                print("Invalid")
    return render(response, "myapp/list.html", {"ls": ls})
```

and this is my list.html:

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% block title %}View List of Items{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ls.name}}</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            {% for item in ls.listitem_set.all %}
                {% if item.complete == TRUE %}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" , value="clicked" , name="c{{item.id}}" checked>{{item.text}}</li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><input type="checkbox" , value="clicked" , name="c{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" , name="save" , value="save">Save</button>  <!--Updates checked items -->
        <input type="text" , name="new">
        <button type="submit" , name="newItem" , value="newItem"> Add Item </button>  <!--Adds new items -->
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I open `127.0.0.1:8000/list/1` in my broweser, it displays my 1st list with items and corresponding checkboxes. When I click on a checkbox it gets 'checked' but when I press save and reload, the box is unchecked again. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to be certain without seeing the page in action, but I would try:

1. Changing your Django HTML tag if/else condition to 'True' rather than 'TRUE' as I believe in Python it's case sensitive.
2. Ensure you're ending up in the right path in your if/else statement.